# The result shows in console log but not on the page when using useRef & useCallback in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know extracting data from API is asynchronous and the state would not be available at such time, So we are supposed to use useCallBack, but even though the Data logged successfully but not shows on the webpage.

This is what I did.

```
const HomePage = (props: any) => {
    const news = props.listNews; // used useCallBack and the data got from the API and logged successfully

    const trending: MainNewsData[] = [];

    const trendingRef = useRef<MainNewsData[]>([]);

    const getNews = useCallback(() => {

        for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
            const e = news[i];
            if (e.category_title === 'Trending') trending.push(e);
            maxHeap.insert(e);
        }
        trendingRef.current = [...trending];

        console.log("trendingRef", trendingRef) // logged successfully
    }, [trendingRef]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, [getNews]);

    return (
        <>
            {< TrendingNews className={''} currentTrendingNews={trendingRef.current.slice(0, 6)} />}
        </>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I don't want to use the filter function because I have 8 categories, So using the filter function 8 times is expensive.

I appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting a ref will not rerender the component. try using useState instead.

```js
const HomePage = (props: any) => {
    const news = props.listNews; // used useCallBack and the data got from the API and logged successfully

    const trending: MainNewsData[] = []; 

    const [trendingState, setTrendingState] = useState([])

    const getNews = useCallback(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
            const e = news[i];
            if (e.category_title === 'Trending') trending.push(e);
            maxHeap.insert(e);
        }
        setTrendingState([...trending]);

        console.log("trendingState", trendingState) // logged successfully
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, [getNews]);

    return (
        <>
            {< TrendingNews className={''} currentTrendingNews={trendingState.slice(0, 6)} />}
        </>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: you're correct about ref, however, if I tried to use UseState and added the "trending" as a dependency, the code will enter inside an infinite loop.
I added the news inside the useCallBack and kept your line about useState but without added trending as a dependency. and now it's work.
I understand why it's work now since the useState force the page to rerender, but why the previous code doesn't work even with useCallBack still didn't get it ‍♀️
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Objects are pointers in javascript and since you are declaring the object INSIDE this function, it is creating a NEW object every iteration. This will have a different pointer value. Thus when it compares the two pointers, it will think that the value has been updated and should re-render. When the component re-renders, it creates a new object and that's why it created the infinite loop. You can fix this by moving your `const trending` outside of the function or by using a ref for it instead. However, I don't see why you would want it to be a dependency in the first place.